# .net mvc default app, navigation menu is not horizontal

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

Using VS2017, I created a new MVC web project. 
When I run the default app, the navigation menu bar appears normal.

[image]

However, when I upgraded the Nuget packages (only Bootstrap from 3.3.7 to 4.1.3 and Popper 1.14) and then ran the default app. Viola, **the menu items, which normally runs horizontal, are all hidden. When I click  the little icon to the left of "Application name", the menu shows up as a dropdown (see image)**.

Again, I did nothing other than upgrade the Nuget packages. So bootstrap and a bunch of other items got updated.

I can't imagine that I am the only one seeing this, yet I cannot find other examples/issues. I checked the Content folder, BundleConfig.cs, _Layout.cshtml and they all look normal.

I checked F12 and there are no broken links to stylesheets, etc.

Anyone else see this?

[image: menu broken]

Here is menu code from _Layout.cshtml.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And BundleConfig.cs is standard looking:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

Comment: Did the Bootstrap major version change? Did you check the docs for breaking changes?

Comment: A lot of classes were changed in bootstrap 4 so its possible the classes you are using is not valid anymore. Here is a working exampl: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: This problem is typical of upgrading from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to Bootstrap 4.0.0. You'll need to slightly restructure your code to accommodate for the new version.

Comment: Thanks guys. It all makes sense now. The bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.1.3 completely rewrote the navbar classes. So MVC navigation menu (bit older version) completely breaks. @agDev - the w3schools link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of classes were changed in bootstrap 4 so its possible the classes you are using is not valid anymore.

[Here](http://w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp) is a working example of a navbar in Bootstrap 4.

Check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for Bootstrap 4 navbar documentation.